# Grafana Panel Dev: Using external Lib in plugins

Tags: javascript, three.js, grafana, panels

I am trying to use three.js to render some interesting images based on metrics. I am really new to grafana dev and am having trouble figuring out where and when to load three.js and some other js files. At the moment I am trying to load it in the module.html but this does not seem right, since I don't thing it can be loaded after the page is loaded (I think). How would I load these libs to use? Sorry if this is in the docs, they seem to be inaccessible today...

Answer (score 1):

We use S3 for the docs and [it was down today](https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/28/amazon-aws-s3-outage-is-breaking-things-for-a-lot-of-websites-and-apps/).

There is currently no way to inject an external lib in a plugin via systemjs in Grafana so the way to include it is to just add the js file to your plugin and then import it.

Here are some examples:

- The gauge panel [imports the D3 library](https://github.com/briangann/grafana-gauge-panel/blob/master/src/ctrl.js#L8) that is in the `src/external` folder:

  `import * as d3 from './external/d3.v3.min';`
- The Diagram panel [imports the Mermaid library](https://github.com/jdbranham/grafana-diagram/blob/master/src/diagramControl.js#L1) that is in the `dist/libs/mermaid/dist` directory:

  `import './libs/mermaid/dist/mermaidAPI';`

This only needs to be done for libraries that you want to include in the plugin. You can install as many build time plugins as you want (linting, sass, grunt plugins etc.). You can also use the libraries that Grafana has already - Lodash, Flot, jQuery.